# TEXT SIZE ON PRINTER DOES NOT WORK ANDROID

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I am developing an app and I need to print a large text, and I am using the following settings

```
byte[] FONT_3X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x21};
                byte[] FONT_2X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x11};
                byte[] FONT_1X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x00};
                byte[] ALLINEA_CT = {0x1B, 0x61, 0x01};
                byte[] INIT = {27, 64};
                byte[] SELECT_FONT_A = {27, 33, 2};
                outputStream.write(INIT);
                outputStream.write(ALLINEA_CT);
                outputStream.write(SELECT_FONT_A);
                outputStream.write(FONT_2X);
                outputStream.write(texto.getBytes());
                outputStream.write("\n".getBytes());
```

FONT_2X works fine but changing to FONT_3X displays text in normal size. Do you have any idea what it might be?, Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Font_2X is just a name, you need to change the {0x1D, 0x21, 0x11} to others

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**`FONT_3X`** is the font-size that you need for this:

```java
byte[] FONT_3X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x21};

byte[] FONT_2X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x11};

byte[] FONT_1X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x00};
```